# To create a common transaction for IdentityDbContext and ApplicationDbContext in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

I have my IdentityDbContext with user and roles as below.

```
public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AdditionalIdentityUser, AdditionalApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
    }
}
```

I have my ApplicationDbContext for other tables.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have my create user code where in I use both the IdentityDbContext to crteate the user and role record and the Application Dbcontext to make a few other updates. I want to do this in one transaction.

So I have :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateModel model)
{
    //context here is the context injected through dependency injection.
     using (var appdbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {        

            //Creating using identity Context
            var user = await userManager.CreateAsync(model.User);

           //Random code which uses ApplicationDbContext
            var updateCount = context.Table1.Update();
            appdbContextTransaction .Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            appdbContextTransaction.Rollback();
        }
}
```

But on an exception only the appdbcontext values change and not the ones created using identity. How do I create one comprehensive transaction which can cover both contexts?

EDIT : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31041479/7793375) question seems similar but the answer does not help.

Comment: Does declaring userManager inside the using block help?